# I can't use datepicker on elements added through $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

Here is my code so far:

```
$('body').on('change', '.dropdown', function() {
    $.ajax({
        success: function(res) {
            if(res.success == true) { 
                 return elements with class .hasdatepicker

                 getdatepicker('.hasdatepicker');
            }
        }
    });
});

function getdatepicker(elem) {
    $(elem).each(function(){
        var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
        var objdate = $(this);
        $(this).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '1950:currentYear',
            onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
                objdate.val(month+'/'+inst.selectedDay+'/'+year);
            }
        });
        $(this).attr("readonly","true");
    });
}
```

I know it gets to `getdatepicker` because it adds the `readonly` attribute to the elements.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: I'm really sorry for the confusion. I updated my answer. My function `getdatepicker` is actually inside the `success` call..

Comment: @DaveNewton Exactly - Asynchronous JavaScript And XML.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the getDatePicker() in the success function of your ajax call.
The way you are calling it now is before the success method is run:
Example:

HTML:

```
<div id='test'>test</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function() {
$.ajax({
    success: function() {
        $("#test").addClass('hasdatepicker')
         getdatepicker($('.hasdatepicker')); //SUCCESS
    }
});

getdatepicker($('.hasdatepicker')); //FAIL
});

function getdatepicker(elem) {
    elem.html('success');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your function in ajax callback, it's because when `getdatepicker` runs `ajax.success` has not been ran yet, since `ajax.success` is as asynchronous.

```
$('body').on('change', '.dropdown', function() {
    $.ajax({
        success: function () { 
        //return elements with class .hasdatepicker ;
        getdatepicker('.hasdatepicker');}
    });
});
```